# Update custom field in CiviCase using batch profile?

Tags: profile, civicase, batches

I made a custom field in CiviCase and since I have hundreds of records where this field needs updating, I'd prefer to do it using batch update with profile.

I made a profile containing the custom field plus one other case field.

So I've tried:
Find the records using advanced search, display the results as contacts - the profile I want to use is not available.
Find the records using advanced search, display the results as cases - batch update via profile is not available. 
Find the records using 'find Cases' from CiviCase - batch update via profile is not available.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

There is a write up [here](https://civicrm.org/blog/colemanw/pushing-the-envelope-with-civicase) about using the API. May not be a lot of help to you but worth adding to the thread. I found it, and your question, while similarly searching for a solution to needing to 'bulk update' Cases - and having found and failed (in our situation) with VBO and Views it may be a case, for us at least, that we need to do some more development with VBO and civicrm Entities